# Create Interceptor to calculate execution time of each Web APIs in C#

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, invoke

I am working on AngularJS, WebApi. Have angular services to fetch data from database using Entity-Framework LINQ.

So, when I run my app, I want to see how much time my web api took to return response from server?

How can we do it?

Comment: You can use `ActionFilterAttribute` to get exception time. On `OnActionExecuting` start the `Stopwatch` and  stop it `OnActionExecuted` where you get Elapsed time.

Comment: Second way is to create your custom [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware)

Comment: @Div, Ok, Please let me know the answer as I need very much. I am stuck in this code from last 2 days.

Comment: Did you manage to implement this?

Comment: @Ggalla - No, I am not able to implement this code.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this thing.

First way is to use ActinoFilter. For that refer [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070781/4753489)

Second way is to use [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware)

Add new class file, here it's `LoggingMiddleware`

```
public class LoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    LoggingDataAccess _loggingDataAccess; // your data access
    readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, LoggingDataAccess loggingDataAccess)
    {
        _next = next;
        _loggingDataAccess = loggingDataAccess;
    }

   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
   {
          // start request time 
          _stopwatch.Start();

          await _next.Invoke(context);

          // end request time and get elapsed milliseconds
          _stopwatch.Stop();

          // save time to your table 
          var time= _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

          //reset stopwatch
          _stopwatch.Reset();
   }
}
```

Add your Middleware in `Startup.cs` *(ASP.NET Core)*

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app...)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<LoggingMiddleware>();
}
```

Hope this helps!